# Metal King: A JavaScript Game

Tags: javascript, beginner, battle-simulation

I started to learn programming just a few days ago. And I've written code for a simple original game for practice, using some knowledge of JavaScript that I have gained so far.

Is the following code properly written? I'm especially concerned about the use of "Math.floor", "Math.random", "function", and "if / else".

Incidentally, "Metal King" is the name of a monster in the game, and "Angelo" is a character.

```
alert("Metal Kings (A, B, and C) have appeared!");



// Which Metal King (A, B, or C) will Angelo decide to attack? \
// 33% probability for each.

var MetalKingABC = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);


if (MetalKingABC === 1) {
    MetalKingABC = "Metal King A";
}
else if (MetalKingABC === 2) {
    MetalKingABC = "Metal King B";
}
else {
    MetalKingABC = "Metal King C";
}



var WhichOneToAttack = function(MonsterName) {

    alert("Angelo is about to attack " + MonsterName + ".");


    // Metal King has a 50% chance of fleeing the battle.

    var FleeOrFight = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);


    if (FleeOrFight === 1) {
        alert(MonsterName + " flees like lightning!");
        // The battle ends here before Angelo attacks.
    }

    else // Metal King stays, and Angelo attacks.
    {
        // 70% chance of MISS, 20% of ONE damage, 10% of Critical.

        var MissOneCritical = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

        if (MissOneCritical <= 7) {
            alert(MonsterName + " swiftly evades Angelo's attack.");
        }

        else if (MissOneCritical <= 9) {
            alert("Angelo inflicts 1 point of damage on " + MonsterName + ".");
        }

        else {
            // The damage dealt by a critical hit can range from 197 to 256 points.

            var CriticalRange = 197 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);

            alert("Angelo lands a critical hit on " + MonsterName + ", dealing massive \
            damage of " + CriticalRange + " points! Angelo defeats " + MonsterName + ".");

            // When defeated, Metal King drops a shield with an 80% probability.

            var ShieldDrop = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

            if (ShieldDrop <= 8) {
                alert(MonsterName + " drops a shield. Angelo obtains a Diamond Shield!");                
            }
            else {
            // No code is written in this else portion, since Metal King didn't drop \
            // any item.  
            }
        }
    }
};

// Finally, call the function.

WhichOneToAttack(MetalKingABC);
```

Comment: Are you concerned about how you're using `if`/`else`, or that you're using them?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes    Actually, on both counts. I ended up with quite a lot of "if / else" statements, so I was wondering if they were used in an acceptable manner as well as if I could get around its repeated use in favour of some other code.

Comment: `if`/`else` statements are really common, and using lots is almost never a symptom of bad code.

Comment: I am confused. Is Metal King a king who is made of metal, or the king of all metals? or perhaps both?

Comment: @EricLippert I suppose the King of Metal is a far cousin of Michael Jackson :)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes    Oh, I see. Thank you. Might I ask you something else? Your comment has the "if / else" bit displayed in grey background. How can I do the same?

Comment: @EricLippert   Metal King is an-ingame monster whose body is comprised of the hardest material ever known to man. Here in Japan, this particular video game, and by extension "Metal King", is  quite well-known. I wouldn't have thought the name could be confused with anything to do with heavy metal music, of all things. :)

Comment: Use back ticks (`) on either side.

Comment: @pourraitpuet-etre There's some incoherent stuff in your numbers! If Angelo has 70% chances to miss, why would the Metal King flee 50% of the time? I mean, that's not how fighting works, if you have advantage, stay. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your game doesn't have a name! (Which is why I renamed the question like that...)

A few direct things to focus on:

> ```
> if (MetalKingABC === 1) {
>     MetalKingABC = "Metal King A";
> }
> else if (MetalKingABC === 2) {
>     MetalKingABC = "Metal King B";
> }
> else {
>     MetalKingABC = "Metal King C";
> }
> ```

This is not how you do that.

Instead of using `1 + Math.floor` get rid of the `1` as `0` is a valid array index, and is helpful in many situations.

Instead of using `* 2`, alongside an array, use `* array.length`.

Instead of using an `if-else` loop with duplicate logic (string assignment), use an array instead.

```
var metalKingTypes = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var metalKing = metalKingTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * metalKingTypes.length)];
```

Instead of using `MissOneCritical`: use a `switch`

After you decide who to attack, and then attack them, the game is over! Even if you miss or only do 1 damage!

### Set a `isActive` variable to keep the game going.

A few indirect things:

- `WhichOneToAttack`: could be better named: `DecideOpponent`
- `FleeOrFight`: You naming structure should be `camelCase` where the first word is entirely lowercase.
- You can use this to get a random `true` or `false` value: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)`

---

### Your structure:

You have a bunch of loose functions that aren't linked to one another in any other way than the fact that they call each other.

Use a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) structure, or a [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) chain, that way you can avoid passing parameters around:

Taking those changes into consideration would give you something like this:

```js
    function Game(){
        alert("Metal Kings (A, B, and C) have appeared!");
            
        /* Which Metal King (A, B, or C) will Angelo decide to attack?
         * 33% probability for each.
         */
            
    
        var metalKingTypes = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
        this.monster = "Metal King " + metalKingTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * metalKingTypes.length)];
        this.isActive = true;
        while (this.isActive) {
            this.DecideOpponent();
        }
    }
    Game.prototype.DecideOpponent = function(){
        alert("Angelo is about to attack " + this.monster + ".");
    
        // Metal King has a 50% chance of fleeing the battle.

        var fleeOrFight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    
        if (fleeOrFight) {
            alert(this.monster + " flees like lightning!");
            // The battle ends here before Angelo attacks.
            return false;
        }
        // 70% chance of MISS, 20% of ONE damage, 10% of Critical.
        var attackOptions = ['evade', 'normal', 'critical'];
    
        var attack = attackOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * attackOptions.length)];
        switch (attack) {
            case 'evade':
                alert(this.monster + " swiftly evades Angelo's attack.");
                break;
            case 'normal':
                alert("Angelo inflicts 1 point of damage on " + this.monster + ".");
                break;
            case 'critical':
                var CriticalRange = 197 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);
    
                alert("Angelo lands a critical hit on " + this.monster + ", dealing massive " +
                      "damage of " + CriticalRange + " points! Angelo defeats " + this.monster + ".");
    
                // When defeated, Metal King drops a shield with an 80% probability.
    
                var shieldDrop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    
                if (shieldDrop) {
                    alert(this.monster + " drops a shield. Angelo obtains a Diamond Shield!");
                }
                this.isActive = false;
                break;
        }
    };
    
    // Finally, call the function.
    
    var g = new Game();
```

---

Additionally, instead of using `alert` consider building each line of the game to the `console` or to a HTML element.

Something like:

```
function buildToHTML(text){
    var field = document.getElementById('gameField');
    field.text += text;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ooh, an `alert`-based game. The good old days. However, for the more tech-savvy, playing with the console will be a better experience. Very... command-liney.

Now the first problem in your code is that your state has no structure. You don't know what the current state of the game is (well, you have `MetalKingABC`). It would be nice if you had a structure that held the game. A simple object structure like this would be fine.

```
var game_state = {
  turn: 'player2', // add as many players
  pase: 'ACTION_PHASE', // INITIAL_PHASE, ACTION_PHASE, BATTLE_PHASE, END PHASE
  player1: {
    name: 'Angelo',
    damage: 25,
    health: 100,
    mana: 100,
    critRate: 0.10,
    evasion: 0.25,
    // and so on
  },
  player2: {
    name: 'MetalKingX',
    damage: 25,
    health: 100,
    mana: 100,
    critRate: 0.10,
    evasion: 0.25,
    // and so on
  }
};
```

Given the info above, I can easily set up rendering commands to show the name of the player, current stats and if any battle happens, I can simply look up the attributes and do calculations. If I wanted to know who's turn it is, I can look at `turn` and run the appropriate commands.

```
function render(gameState){
  // Based on data, write whatever you like to the page
}
```

With the above, the next issue is generating the player data. You can do that by creating a "default" object containing the base stats. You can then use `Object.assign` to copy over the data into another object for use in the game state. The same can be done with the player.

```
var metalKings = [{
  name: 'Metal King A',
  damage: 200,
 ...
},{
  name: 'Metal King B',
  damage: 200,
 ...
},{
  name: 'Metal King C',
  damage: 200,
 ...
}]

// Select a metal king randomly and copy over its base data.
Object.assign(gameState.player2, metalKings[Math.random() * 3 | 0]);
```

So now we have covered game state and character creation, let's move to your logic... which doesn't appear to have structure. So let's start by creating your logic.

Game state mutation is just a result of calculation. Given some input, it mutates the data. With that, we can extract operations into function that take in data, and based on that data, calculates the outcome. The key take away in this is that they should be "transparent". Given the same input, the operation should always give the same output, no matter when it's called.

```
function getRemainingHealth(p1Damage, p2Hp, p2Armor){
  return p2Hp - (p1Damage - p2Armor);
}

function evade(evasionRate){
  // 100% evasion is 1, no evasion is 0. Math.random() range is 0-1.
  return Math.random() <= evasionRate;
}

function crit(critRate){
  return Math.random() <= critRate;
}

function critDamage(unitBaseDamage, critDamage){
  return unitBaseDamage * critDamage;
}
```

Also notice that the game state only holds "base data" (hp, damage, rates etc.) Critical strike damage is an example of "derived data". You don't store the crit damage value, just it's constituents (base damage, crit rate, and crit percentage). This prevents your data from going out of sync.

Now the basics are covered, can then formulate your state machine

1. **INITIAL**: render ui, prep data etc.
2. render (initial ui on turn start)
3. **ACTION**: select action
4. render (reflect the action taken by player)
5. **BATTLE**: compute stuff (damage, damage reductions, crits, remaining hps etc.)
6. render (this is where the fireworks happen)
7. **END**: sign off (post battle effects, buffs/debuffs, change turn etc.)
8. render (post-battle effects, hand over messages, end of battle messages etc.)
9. repeat

Each of these can be separate functions, which passes in the game state. Each phase function can then mutate the state.

```
function doStuff(phase, gameState){
  switch(phase):
    case: 'INITIAL'
      doInitialPhase(gameState);
      break;
    case: 'ACTION'
      doActionPhase(gameState);
      break;
    case: 'BATTLE'
      doBattlePhase(gameState);
      break;
    case: 'END'
      doEndPhase(gameState);
      break;
}

// Battle phase pseudo code
function doBattlePhase(state){
  console.log(state.turn + 'is attacking');
  if(!didEvade(p2)) state[p2].hp = calculateRemainingHp(p1Damage);
  ...and so on...
}
```

Now notice that I never made mention of an "enemy". That's right. That's because in a game, your enemy *is also a player*. Yes, and that's how AI games and multiplayer games work. Instead of an actual player dispatching commands, the game gets commands from an AI engine, or over the network (from some remote player). The game doesn't make a distinction of who's doing what. All the game will ever know is that some action does some changes to some data.